# C# GetFileAsync Permission Denied

Tags: c#

In the C# app I am writing, I created a blank text file called "WriteLines.txt" in my Solution Explorer using the Add New Item feature.

However, When I try to modify this text file and set its content equal to a string I named output using the following lines of code, I get the Permission Denied exception on the "`FileIO.WriteLineAsync code (E_ACCESSDENIED)`":

```
var file1 = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("WriteLines.txt");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file1, output);
```

The "WriteLines.txt" file is not read-only, I already checked its properties.

Does anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Since the program runs under the user's credentials, you should probably be storing files that need to be modified during execution in a folder owned by the user. That is, in appdata or the home folder or whatever.

Comment: I changed the code to:

var file1 = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("%AppData%\\WriteLines.txt");
                    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file1, output);

In order to access the AppData folder, and I copied the WriteLines.txt file over there. I then got a FileNotFound exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other option is to make sure that you run VS as an administrator. So when you run VS right click the exe and select run as administrator. That should elevate permissions.